# Is there a record of species kept in zoos worldwide and number of individuals? If yes, can one have access to it?

Tags: zoology, ecology, conservation-biology

Looking for the number and species of wild cats kept in zoos to assess the potential pool of individuals available for reintroduction programmes.

Answer (score 1):

A potential data source could the data base that stores zoo animal data, where the most comprehensive (to my knowledge) is [Species360 ZIMS (Zoological Information Management System)](https://www.species360.org/products-services/zoo-aquarium-animal-management-software/). It contains animal records and current breeding programmes, but also information on how to care for animals (best-practices and studbooks).

In your case, the [ZIMS for Studbooks](https://www.species360.org/products-services/zims-for-studbooks/) module should be relevant, which contains:

> ZIMS for Studbooks improves Studbook Keeper efficiency and record accuracy with suggested animals, notification of records updates, and extensive data quality tools. [...] enabling users to conduct intensive population analysis, improving species and conservation management

However, I do not have access to the data base myself, so I cannot say how accessible the data is. If you are connected to a zoo, teaching institution or research facility you can however apply for access and a membership, but I don't know the specifics of this process (or possible costs). It might be worth checking out either way.